# Using both POST and GET Ajax calls for the same WebMethod in ASMX Web Service

Tags: asp.net, ajax, service, asmx

I can't seem to call a web service method from Ajax with both POST and GET.

Initially only the POST would work and GET would causes this error:

> {"Message":"An attempt was made to
>   call the method \u0027getData\u0027
>   using a GET request, which is not
>   allowed.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

I fixed that by adding this attribute: `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]` but now GET causes this error:

> {"Message":"An attempt was made to
>   call the method \u0027getData\u0027
>   using a POST request, which is not
>   allowed.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

So is it true that you can only use either POST or GET and not both from Ajax?  Does anyone know why this occurs or if there is a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You **can** configure an ASMX service to respond to both GET and POST, but I don't believe there's any reasonable way to make them respond to GETs with JSON.  Without the JSON serialization, they aren't really appropriate for use in AJAX calls.

If you want to request JSON via GET, you'll need to use an HttpHandler or WCF service.

Also, you should [be sure that you know what you're doing before exposing JSON via GET](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx).

Comment: I understand the risk but the GET requests are meant for use with JSONP.

Answer (score 2):

ASMX webservices support JSON GET's using the following syntax.

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class TestService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function


End Class
```

Comment: Sorry its late, just realized you want both gets and posts to work at the same time. Will let you know if I find a way...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have two seperate web services, one for GET and one POST

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True)> 
Public Function HelloWorld_GET() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld_POST() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this with WCF. ASMX web services are now considered to be "legacy technology", and Microsoft has said they are now in "maintenance mode", and are unlikely to have bugs fixed.